# What scriptural evidence exists in support of our spirit's pre-mortal existence?

Tags: exegesis, souls

Some denominations believe that our spirit existed before we were born on this earth. What scriptural/historical evidence do they use to lay support for their claims?

Answer (score 3):

There is no Scriptural evidence that I find to support that claim. However, I believe that the following scripture does support the idea that not only life, but the Soul begins at conception.

> Genesis 2:7 KJV And the LORD God formed man of the dust of the ground, and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life; and man became a living soul.

Many who do espouse the idea of pre-mortal existence base their assumption on:

> Jeremiah 1:5 KJV Before I formed thee in the belly I knew thee; and before thou camest forth out of the womb I sanctified thee, and I ordained thee a prophet unto the nations.

That Scripture however would appear to validate God's omniscience and not mans pre-mortal existence.

Comment: Problem with premortal life claim of LDS is that it is appealing to those seeking advice for their hard circumstances in life on earth. At least it is appealing to me. But I cannot buy into this "as God was so man is and as God is so shall we" - claim or three different places of heaven. But I guess I have to seek advice to sometimes hard circumstances from Jesus in prayer.